# object Angular to array

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object

[image: 1]

How can I get only the data array from the observable response ?, I need to get the values ​​of cat_id,cat_name,cat_description but not the sql_types array

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "cat_name": "Topografía",
            "cat_description": "Servicios de topografía en general",
            "cat_id": 1
        },
        {
            "cat_name": "Estructuras hormigón",
            "cat_description": "subcontratas de estructuras de hormigón ",
            "cat_id": 3
        }
    ],
    "sqlTypes": {
        "cat_name": 12,
        "cat_description": 12,
        "cat_id": 4
    }
}
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Can't you just make the BE not return sqlTypes in your respone?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your observable and map it to the object you want.

Only your data will be availible in the example below

```
Observable.pipe(map(resp => resp.data)).subscribe(data=> //do something)
```